# how should I return a container with some random image from a list when tapped on a container with in the same page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

And here's the list

```
//int randomIndex=Random().nextInt(hes.length);
  int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(hes.length);

List<HappyList> hes = [
  HappyList(
    name: 'somename',
    imageUrl: 'images/frozen2.png',
    url: 'someweblink',
  ),
  HappyList(
    name: 'somename1',
    imageUrl: 'images/adum.jpg',
    url: 'someweblink',
  ),

];
```

so please help me to generate a random image each time when I tap on the container  it should  return a container with some random image from a  list when tapped on a container with in the same page

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, like your container code and where do you exactly want to show this random image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the Container in a `GestureDetector`, the use the `onTap` method

Like this

```
int index;

GestureDetector(
   child: Container(),
   onTap : (){
      setState(() => index = Random().nextInt(hes.length));
   },
);
```